# Convert JavaScript TemplateLiteral to python dictionnary

Tags: javascript, python, dictionary

I would like to parse a JavaScript code that defines data that contains TemplateLiterals (``).

Here is an easy example

```
let data = {
cat: 'Retail', name: 'Dollar Mania', value: 30,
icon: 'img/dollarmania.png',
desc: `
        Best store in town! 

        <p>Founded in 2011</p>

`}
```

What is the best pythonic way to convert this JS object to python dictionary ?

Comment: data is not a string. data is an object

Comment: @MikeScotty, yes you're right!

Comment: Could you please tell us how are you using JS and python in collaboration?

Comment: I have .html files that contain JS scripts. I want to open the files and extract the data from them. I want to handle the data as a python dictionary, which makes sense to me since it seems to have a pretty similar structure..

Answer (score 0):

The safest way would be to run the object definition in JavaScript, then use JavaScript to export it to a format that Python can read natively. JSON is a suitable format for this. This will avoid you having to write a JavaScript parser in Python, which would have to account for many edge cases.

In JavaScript, convert the object in the local variable `data` to JSON and then print it to stdout:

```js
const dataAsJsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(dataAsJsonString);
```

Your Python program can use Python’s built-in JSON parsing library to decode the output of the JavaScript:

```py
import json

dataAsJsonString = sys.stdin.read()
data = json.loads(dataAsJsonString)
```

To pass the data from JavaScript to Python, you can run the JavaScript program with Node and pipe its output to your Python program: `node dataSource.js | python data_reader.py`. Or if you can’t run your JavaScript with Node, you could copy the console output to your clipboard and then pipe your OS’s command to paste to your Python program, e.g. `pbpaste | python data_reader.py` or `xclip -out -selection clipboard | python data_reader.py`.